# Are Character Points as used for advancement and as used for increasing a roll the same thing?

Tags: star-wars-d6

The Star Wars D6 (revised and expanded) rulebook mentions character points in two usages for character points:

1. Character points may be used to improve my character (by increasing skills, attributes, force powers, etc.)
2. Character points may be used to increase a single roll.

Are these both referring to the same thing?  The two usages are different enough that I am wondering if they are even the same thing. If I only gain character points as a reward for adventuring, I would hate to waste them on improving individual rolls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sometimes you just have to make a roll.**

Yes, they are the same thing. It's pretty rare for a PC to use them for that (from the games I've run) but if they *really* want to hit the bad guy they'll do it.

Page 10; revised and expanded edition:

> If you make a particularly bad roll, or if you want to improve a roll you've already made, you may use a Character Point to roll and additional die and add it to that skill roll. (snip) For now, you'll just be allowed to use one Character Point to improve a single skill roll. Don't use up your Character Points too quickly. You never know when you'll *really* need them. It's always good to have a few around to help your character through the adventure's climax!

p160-161 Has more on character points which also points out that they're used for Character Advancement, but from the list of categories that can have baring on getting more character points for the end of an adventure; if a player uses Character Points to try and do something "In Character" I'd be inclined as a GM to give them that point back, your mileage may vary.